# How to generate a series of bisection points of a given line segment?

Tags: function-construction

I want to get the coordinates of the bisection points for a given line segment to a specified resolution. For example, when the line is given by {0,0} and {1,0}, the output coordinates should be {0.5,0} for the first iteration, and then {0.25,0} and {0.75,0} for the second iteration, and so on, until the distances between those points are less than some resolution, say 1/16. Is there a convenient way?

Comment: @Kuba, Yes, {.5, 0} has been generated in the first iteration and saved.

Comment: @Kuba, I accepted it based on the illustration. Seems a little rush. :P

Comment: @Kuba am sorry if I misinterpreted the question

Comment: @ubpdqn You don't have to be sorry :) if this is what OP needs, great, but the question does not fit then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a cute method based on the way *Mathematica* reduces fractions. Suppose you want to divide the line into 16ths:

```
n = 16;
x = Reverse @ GatherBy[Range[n - 1]/n, Denominator]

(* {{1/2}, {1/4, 3/4}, {1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8}, 
  {1/16, 3/16, 5/16, 7/16, 9/16, 11/16, 13/16, 15/16}} *)
```

The actual coordinates can be obtained with:

```
line = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
Map[{1 - #, #}.line &, x, {-1}]

(* {{{1/2, 0}}, {{1/4, 0}, {3/4, 0}}, {{1/8, 0}, {3/8, 0}, {5/8, 0}, {7/8, 0}}, ... *)
```

Comment: :-)@Simon Woods, amazingly elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an apporach:

```
fun[p_, q_, n_] := 
 Nest[DeleteDuplicates[
    Join @@ Map[
      Function[u, u /. {x_List, y_List} -> {x, Mean[{x, y}], y}], 
      Partition[#, 2, 1]]] &, {p, q}, n]
```

Testing (by plotting):

```
Table[ListPlot[fun[{0, 0}, {1, 0}, j], PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}], {j, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Table[ListPlot[fun[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, j], PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}], {j, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

And for line not through origin:

```
Table[ListPlot[fun[{3, 0}, {1, 1}, j], PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}], {j, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Same code works for 3D:

```
tab = Table[fun[{1, 6, 5}, {10, 2, 2}, j], {j, 0, 5}];
Export["e:/mse/msebisect3d.gif", 
 Table[Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[j]}, Line[j]}], {j, 
   tab}], "DisplayDurations" -> Table[2, {6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ ubpdqn,How about extending to 3D line?

Comment: @novice see update

Answer (score 1):

```
f[i_, j_, lim_] := Table[k, {k, i, j, 2 ^Floor@Log[2, lim] (j - i)}]
g[a_, b_, lim_] := (a (1 - #) + b #) & /@ f[0, 1, lim/Norm[b - a]]
```

So;

```
g[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 1/4]

(* {{0, 0}, {1/8, 1/8}, {1/4, 1/4}, {3/8, 3/8}, {1/2, 1/2}, {5/8, 5/8}, 
    {3/4, 3/4}, {7/8, 7/8}, {1, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Subdivide`:**

The table called `divs` has all the subdivisions whose last entry is being used to depict the most subdivided line determined by the resolution.

*2D case*

```
p1 = {0, 0};
p2 = {1, 1};
n = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]/(1/16);
divs = Table[Subdivide[p1, p2, i], {i, 1, Floor@n}];
Graphics[{Line@divs[[-1]]
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
  , Point@divs[[-1]]
  }]
```

[image]

---

*3D case*

```
p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = {1, 1, 1};
n = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]/(1/16);
divs = Table[Subdivide[p1, p2, i], {i, 1, Floor@n}];
Graphics3D[{Line@divs[[-1]]
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
  , Point@divs[[-1]]
  }]
```

[image]

---

*Historical note*

```
WolframLanguageData["Subdivide"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

> {10.1, DateObject[{2015, 3, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.]}