# How to check if a line segment intersects with a polygon?

Tags: computational-geometry

The naive method is to bisect the line segment iteratively [as asked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39597/how-to-generate-a-series-of-bisection-points-of-a-given-line-segment), and then check the bisection points using [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon).

Would there be an other way?

I'm using v9.

For example,

```
list = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 
11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {13.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 1.1}, {1.3, 
2.4}, {2.45, 4.7}};
Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 10}, {20, 0}}], Black, Polygon[list]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Öskå Thanks. I'm working with v9, but I will check v10.

Comment: Why do you need to bisect? (1) Check if an endpoint is inside. If not, then (2) Check if the segment intersects a segment bounding the polygon.

Comment: In V10  `Solve` with geometric regions is very comfortable,  if a bit slow...

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, unfortunately that fails if the polygon is nonconvex.

Comment: @novice: No, Daniel's method still works with nonconvex polygons. Do you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: @Rahul, the short red line seems intersect with segment bounding the polygon.

Comment: The short red line does not seem to intersect with the polygon boundary segments, altough it intersects with the convex hull of the polygon. That, or my eyes need serious reevaluation.

Comment: By "a segment bounding the polygon" Daniel means a line segment on the boundary of the polygon, *i.e.*, an edge of the polygon. The short red line does not intersect any of your polygon's ten edges.

Comment: @Rahul, my bad. I thought "bounding the polygon" means convex hull.

Comment: relevant  : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/find-intersection-of-pairs-of-straight-lines/51425#51425.  Note for non-convex polygons the point-inside test is only useful if you find one end in and one out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using v9, I would suggest using the undocumented function - `` Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ `` which does exactly what you want:

```
plist = {Line[{{20, 10}, {20, 0}}], Polygon[list]};
Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ[plist]
Graphics[MapThread[{##} &, {{Red, Blue}, plist}]]
(* False *)
```

[image]

which is also in v10.

Comment: @ rcollyer, your method is about 60 times faster than using RegionIntersection in V10

Comment: `RegionIntersection` returns a region, while ``Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ`` just tests whether they intersect or not. In many ways, the former is a more involved process, so I expect it to be slower.

Comment: @ rcollyer, for the case of contact, they give different answers. e.g. Line[{{9.10, 11.34}, {14, 9}}] (*contacts with the polygon*)`RegionIntersection` gives True, while ``Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ`` gives False. How to include the contact case into the intersect? When the line lies completely inside in the polygon they also give different answers.

Answer (score 12):

In v10 this is a one-liner:

```
RegionDimension@RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 10}, {20, 0}}], Polygon[list]]] > -∞
```

because an [empty region](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmptyRegion.html) has dimension $-\infty$. I do wish there was a `NonemptyQ` predicate one could use directly, though.

Answer (score 8):

A "solution" using *v10* would be: `RegionQ@DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[r1, r2]`.

For example:

```
r1 = Line[{{0, 10}, {20, 0}}];
r2 = Polygon[{{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 11.9},
              {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {13.3, 7.7}, {0.6,1.1}, {1.3, 2.4}, {2.45, 4.7}}];
g = Show[Graphics[{r1, r2}]];
ri = DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[r1, r2];
RegionQ@ri
```

> ```
> True
> ```

With `r1 = Line[{{0, 10}, {-20, 0}}];` one will have `False`.

Showing the intersection if it exists:

```
If[RegionQ@ri, 
  Show[
    DiscretizeRegion /@ {r1, r2},
    HighlightMesh[DiscretizeRegion[ri], Style[#, Red] & /@ {0, 1}]],
  g]
```

will give the following figures for `{20, 0}` and `{-20, 0}`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

With `r1 = Line[{{10, 10}, {12, 10}}]`:

> ```
> False
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Side note (aka bug?):

Can someone please confirm this?

```
RegionQ[DiscretizeRegion@ RegionIntersection[#, r2]] & /@ 
  {Line[{{5, 10}, {12, 10}}], Line[{{5, 10.1}, {12, 10}}]}
```

> DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region RegionIntersection[<<2>>]. >>
>
> ```
> {False, True}
> ```

While it does intersect with `Line[{{5, 10}, {12, 10}}]`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Strange, I get `True` for all cases, even the ones that don't intersect. Which makes sense to me: an empty region is still a region, just like an empty set/list/graph is still a set/list/graph. (v10.0.1 on Mac, by the way)

Comment: @Rahul Even for `r1 = Line[{{10, 10}, {12, 10}}]`? I'm on Linux 10.0.1.

Comment: Wait, no, now everything is working as expected. And I was sure I restarted the kernel and checked, too... Maybe I made a mistake somewhere. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Rahul The last example doesn't give you `{False, True}`?

Comment: Oh, yes it does. By "as expected" I meant "as in your answer". Yes, it does look like a bug. `RegionDimension` correctly returns `1`, though.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah I checked with your answer as well. And it looks like a bug indeed..

Answer (score 6):

Another partial (see caveat) V10-based answer using `Solve`. The nice feature here is that exact solutions are returned (provided the input is exact, too). Caveat: Will only return intersection points on the border of the polygon. Plus, slow.

I took the liberty to change the initial line into an `InfiniteLine` to add some spice. Essentially this solves for line-polyline intersection:

```
vtx = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 
     11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {13.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 1.1}, {1.3, 
     2.4}, {2.45, 4.7}} // Rationalize;

line = InfiniteLine[{{0, 10}, {20, 20}}];

sol = Solve[{x, y} ∈ line && {x, y} ∈ Line@Append[vtx, vtx[[1]]], {x, y}]

(*{{x -> 736/185, y -> 2218/185}, {x -> 3493/510, 
  y -> 13693/1020}, {x -> 721/80, y -> 2321/160}, {x -> 4663/485, 
  y -> 14363/970}}*)

Graphics[{Polygon[vtx], Thick, Red, line, Green, PointSize[0.05], Point[{x, y} /. sol]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a `Polygon`-based approach `Solve` seems only to work with triangles (so an exact solution will still be possible with some additional work). Hopefully this functionality will be much enhanced in the future.

Answer (score 4):

As of V11.1 you can use [`RegionDisjoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint.html).

```
polygon = Polygon[{{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, 
  {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {13.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 1.1}, {1.3, 2.4}, {2.45, 4.7}}];

line = Line[{{0, 10}, {20, 0}}];

!RegionDisjoint[line, polygon]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For a version 9 solution, consider two line segments, the first between $\{x_1,y_1\}$ and $\{x_2,y_2\}$, the second between $\{u_1,v_1\}$ and $\{u_2,v_2\}$. Parameterize points on the two segments with $\{x_1,y_1\}+s~ (\{x_2,y_2\}-\{x_1,y_1\})$ and $\{u_1,v_1\}+t~(\{u_2,v_2\}-\{u_1,v_1\})$, where the parameters $s$ and $t$ must lie between 0 and 1, inclusive. The two segments intersect if there exists a common point on both lines with parameters $s$ and $t$ within their bounds. The common point is found by equating the two expressions, breaking into two equations in two unknowns, and solving for $s$ and $t$.

```
IntersectSegmentsQ[{{x1_,y1_}, {x2_,y2_}}, {{u1_,v1_}, {u2_,v2_}}] :=
   With[{st={{v1-v2, u2-u1},{y1-y2, x2-x1}}.{u1-x1,v1-y1}/((x2-x1)(v1-v2)-(y2-y1)(u1-u2))},
   (0. <= st[[1]] <= 1.) && (0. <= st[[2]] <= 1.) == True]
```

For your small example,

```
Map[IntersectSegmentsQ[{{0,10},{20,0}},#]&, Partition[Join[list, {list[[1]]}], 2, 1]]
```

There are no optimizations here. Of course, for a large number of polygons with a large number of edges along with a large number of line segments, this approach is an **epic** fail.