# Cut a polygon by a line

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a polygon, says, `Polygon[{0,0},{10,0},{10,10}{0,10}]`. I would like to cut it by a line (through two points) and take one half of it. Could you please suggest me the functions I should use? (I am very new to *Mathematica*).

Comment: Which points? Two vertices?

Comment: a general line that goes through 2 points. Thus the line may or may not cut the polygon

Comment: Take a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/how-to-check-if-a-line-segment-intersects-with-a-polygon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess a pretty easy approach is to use `HalfPlane` with your two points that define your line. `RegionDifference` should do the rest.

```
RegionDifference[ 
 Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}], 
 HalfPlane[{{1, 0}, {3, 7}}, {1, 1}]];
RegionPlot[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. `RegionMember[reg][{x, y}]` gives an algebraic representation of the region, which might be useful in certain cases.  I can't immediately see an easy way to get a `Polygon`.  `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg]["BoundaryPolygons"]` is unsatisfying.

Comment: that's a simple awesome answer - thank you

Answer (score 2):

in MMA v10 (although it is slow) you can use:

```
Clear[r];
r[point1_, point2_] := 
 ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}] && 
   y >= point2[[2]] + (point2[[2]] - point1[[2]])/(
      point2[[1]] - point1[[1]]) (x - point2[[1]]), {x, y}]

RegionPlot[r[{2, 2}, {6, 3}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there are a few sorts of answers to the question, like

- a numeric visualization, e.g. a `RegionPlot`
- a system of algebraic conditions,
- a geometric one, i.e. the resulting polygon(s)

Here is a variation on [halirutan's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) use of the geometric computation functionality:

```
reg = RegionIntersection[
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}], 
   HalfPlane[{{1, 0}, {3, 7}}, -{1, 1}]];
```

It is easy to plot with `RegionPlot[reg]` and to get an algebraic system with `RegionMember[reg][{x, y}]`, but some programming seems necessary to get a geometric solution in elementary terms.

The algebraic system is

```
RegionMember[reg][{x, y}]
(*
  (x | y) ∈ Reals && -7 + 7 x - 2 y <= 0 && 
   10 y >= 0 && -10 (-10 + x) >= 0 && -10 (-10 + y) >= 0 && 10 x >= 0
*)
```

We can find boundary polygons of the region by discretizing the region.  Unfortunately, the breaks the edges into smaller line segments.  These can be eliminated by removing points of the polygon that are collinear with its adjacent points.

```
noncollinear[m : {p1_, p2_, p3_}] := 
  MatrixRank[Transpose[m]~Append~{1., 1., 1.}, Tolerance -> 0.00001] == 3;

polys = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg]["BoundaryPolygons"] /. 
  Polygon[pts_] :> Polygon[Pick[pts, noncollinear /@ RotateRight@Partition[pts, 3, 1, 1]]]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], Opacity[0.4], ColorData[97, 1], polys},
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
(*
  {Polygon[{{1.14952*10^-7, 2.98023*10^-7}, {1., 2.98023*10^-7},
            {3.85714, 10.}, {1.14952*10^-7, 10.}}]}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]