# Convexity Coefficient Calculation

Tags: computational-geometry

I would like to probabiistically estimate the convexity coefficient of a `MeshRegion`, described as -

> Given a region $\mathscr{K}$, calculate the probability that a line with randomly chosen endpoints $\{p_1,p_2\}\in\mathscr{K}$, will be wholly contained within $\mathscr{K}$.

(NB - I know how to do this the 'hard way' e.g. directly using the polygon edges / lines, but I'm hoping to take advantage of *Mathematica*'s new-but-not-great geometric computation additions.)

So- here's a $\mathbb{R}^2$ sort-of-not-really convex region (I eventually need $\mathbb{R}^3$ but this makes the demo simpler)

```
rK = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0.1, 0.5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, let's generate some random lines with endpoints in `rK` -

```
SeedRandom[02134];
lines = Table[Line[{RandomPoint[rK], RandomPoint[rK]]}], {20}];
Show[{rK, Graphics[lines]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of the 20 lines, 14 are fully inside `rK`, so the convexity coef is (roughly, of course) 14/20. Based on the tools available for geometric computation in 10.x I can't seem to find a way to test if a *line* (or other `Region` of some kind) is contained within another region. Points are, of course, pretty trivial (e.g. `RegionMember`)

```
Element[{0.1, 0.1}, rK]
```

yields `True`, and the endpoints of the first line in our random list

```
Show[{rK, Graphics[lines[[1]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RegionMember[rK, lines[[1, 1]]]
```

are both `True` but obviously the line itself isn't contained within the region.

Unfortunately, you can't do anything as clever as, say,

```
Element[MeshRegion[lines[[1, 1]], Line[{1, 2}]], rK]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it might be nice to... I've had extremely mixed success with the various computational geometry routines, especially with complicated / 3D `MeshRegion`s that are my day-to-day currency. Does anyone have any insight here that might help?

Comment: Related: [How to check if a line segment intersects with a polygon?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66152/484) Just replacing `RegionIntersection` with `RegionDifference` in [some](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66157/484) of [those](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66158/484) answers should work.

Comment: I have tried various assortments of Boolean stuffs with this but can't seem to hit on the right thing. Most of the time, everything comes out 'unsimplified' like the ```Element``` example. Hmm- I will probe further!

Comment: NB to whosoever 'oversees' the syntax highlighting for this SX, ```RandomPoint``` is a real MMa symbol.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't seem to like `MeshRegion`s. If you keep them as graphics primitives it works: `RegionDimension[RegionDifference[lines[[1]], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0.1, 0.5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]]]` gives `1`, showing that the line is not entirely contained in the polygon.

Comment: Well isn't that fascinating?! Thanks! Now to do a little checking if I can get it to happen in R^3... magic!